# Delphi 2007 IntraWeb times out in production but works as expected on the local development machine

Tags: delphi-2007, intraweb

I have created my first web application using IntraWeb 9 that came with Delphi 2007.  I am a novice when it comes to this. The documentation I've read discusses later versions of Delphi and IntraWeb, so please be kind with my basic questions.

The application produces an interactive web page that runs fine on my local machine. I can also open the web page from other network computers and it runs fine there as well.

I have uploaded the app and support files to a Windows Server 2022 host under IIS. That computer is also the host to our website, and to a Firebird database that is used by this IntraWeb app.

The application runs normally as a stand-alone server on the host, and I can open the web page it creates in the host's browser. The web page behaves as expected. It is not running as a service because I wanted to test and debug before taking that step. I have opened the port it is listening to in the host's Windows Firewall.

It times out after a long interval when I try to browse to the web page from my local computer. The executable is located in a sub-folder of my WordPress website. The firebird database it uses is also in a sub-folder of the WordPress website, but not the same folder as the app.

Now my inexperience shows along with the lack of documentation on the old IntraWeb version. Could it be that IntraWeb 9, that came bundled with D2007, requires a separate license? I don't mind buying one, but if that isn't the solution, why spend the money. If there might be another issue, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Why have you chosen a 16 year old technology no one uses any more to start with?

Comment: This is part of a larger project with over 3.5 million lines of code.  People actually still use Delphi and IntraWeb.

Comment: Do they use Delphi *2007*?

Comment: @ceejayoz Of course.

Answer (score -2):

If you don't already have ping and telnet installed on your local machine do it now. Google will tell you how.
Then ping the server by IP address. If no reply there is a firewall in the way somewhere.  If OK, try telnet ip port which should connect and silently lock up your terminal session. If no connection, that port is being firewalled off. Your corporate network administrator should be able to help.

Comment: Good suggestion, @kiwiron.  Pinging the host's IP address produced a fast reply. When I added the port to the IP (:X999) I got no reply.  I'll try telnet, but I know the port is open for TCP. Maybe I need to open it for UDP as well. Still a novice.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the credit necessary to vote. It seems stupid that the OP can't vote, but people who have not addressed the actual question can.